# Google search showing things that don't exist on my site

Tags: google-search, drupal

There are a few pages on my site (which has been running for 2 years) that have had their content changed. All the URLs are still the same.

So say on Page X I have a block in the sidebar with some text on it, this text was changed a while back however in Google search, the text that is shown in the results is the old text.

This is happening for a few pages. I'm using Drupal 7 if that helps.

Any ideas why? Or what can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Are you sure that you uploaded and published all your changes? Is it possible that these pages are still in your cache?

Comment: Google likely has not revisited these pages or indexed the changes.

Comment: Hi yes the pages are all published and updated and i have manually cleared all cache tables!very strange. Is there anything i can do? i have submitted the site to Google for crawling twice now!

Comment: In Google Search Console, use Fetch as Google and click Render. When done, review the panels to see if your change is there. If it is, then Submit to Index. This actually takes a few days to show up since Google will refetch the page using googlebot. You can confirm this using the Cache option in the SERPs. If the change is not there, then the problem is server-side. You will need to walk down through the processes on your site. You should see the change when you view your site directly using your domain name. Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 to be sure. Let us know how this goes. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google shows in SERP snippet texts, which Google means are best describing your site. The only thing with which you could try to influence the SERP snippet content, is to write good meta description. But there is no warranty, that Google will indeed make use of it.

On the other side, there are not exact times known, after which Google shows the updated text on your site. If you have updated some things on your site, and Google still shows the old content, submit the content of the page to index,. like @closetnoc even recommended. And become sure, that the page you submit, isn't blocked against crawling/indexing and responses with nothing other but 200.

It could happen, that the updated text is placed dynamically by any kind of AJAx/JS etc. which could be closed against crawling - in this case Google will not show the updated text too.

it would be helpful to see a site to get to know about issues preventing new text appear in SERP snippet.